# Dynamically populate drop-down menu with JSON array name

Tags: jquery, json

I want to populate a drop down menu with the object category names. Sound simple, but I can't figure this out. Please help.

for example:

## JSON

```
window.cars =
{

"compact":

[
{ "title": "honda", 
      "type": "accord", 
      "thumbnail": "accord_t.jpg", 
      "image": "accord_large.jpg" },
{ "title": "volkswagon", 
      "type": "rabbit", 
      "thumbnail": "rabbit_t.jpg", 
      "image": "volkswagon_large.jpg" }
],

"trucks":

[
{ "title": "Ford", 
    "type": "f-150", 
    "thumbnail": "ford_t.jpg", 
    "image": "chevy_large.jpg" },
{ "title": "GMC", 
      "type": "silverado", 
      "thumbnail": "gmc_t.jpg", 
      "image": "gmc_large.jpg" }
]
};
```

So "compact" and  "trucks" would populate the dropdown menu.

## HTML + JQUERY

```
$.each(cars, function( k, v){

$('select').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + k + '</option>');

});

}
```

Any ideas why this won't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm looks like you need another level of looping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to 2 types of objects in that JSON. You can populate the  element by doing so:

```
$(function(){
     window.cars = {...}; // JSON

    $.each(cars['compact'], function( k, v){
      $('select').append('<option value="' + k + '">' + v.title + '</option>'); 
    });    
});
```

Or if you must use both objects, you have to loop through each one (assuming that all objects contains similar properties within the array.

```
$(function(){
   window.cars = {...}; // JSON

    var index = 0;
    $.each(cars, function( k, v){
      $.each(v, function(i, obj){
          $('select').append('<option value="' + index + '">' + obj.title + '</option>'); 
          index++;
      });
    });    
});
```